# a[title] not showing expected result

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply styling to just one anchor in a html document. However, I have tried a[title] to try and apply css styling to just that one element, but nothing happens. Why would this not work. I would appreciate some feedback as to how style using this type of format. Thanks

html code

```
<div class="col_2">
       <img src="img/blueman.png" width="70" height="70" class="img_left imgshadow" alt="" />
       <p class="newsSpace"><a href="#" title="logout">Signout</a></p>
   </div>
```

css code

```
a[title] {

      font-size: 24px;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
      /* border-bottom:1px solid #777777; */
      }
```

main menu code

```
#menu li a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/LePZq/

At least in Chrome 27 and IE10. What are you seeing?

Comment: @jao It is not working in ff and IE10? I shall load chrome and see if it works there. However, most of my users use IE and FF so need to try and find alternative.Thanks

Comment: I haven't checked Firefox because I don't have it installed. And it does work in IE10

Comment: @Ankit it is not working in FF and IE10

Comment: @jao no, it does not work in IE10

Comment: Perhaps there is something else in my markup stopping it working.

Comment: Show us what it looks in your IE10 then.

Comment: It should work .. I use the same code experimenting in jsfriddle except font color is set to green, a[title] { color : #0f0; font-size: 24px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; /* border-bottom:1px solid #777777; */ } please experiment here http://jsfiddle.net/Bp6LX/1/ Have you tried to clear cache yet?

Comment: I was under the impression that by just coding a[title] it should work. Do I have to apply classes and li elements to coding? Yes I cleared my cache.

Comment: Obviously there is something in my markup that is stooping it from working because it is obviously working others here.

Comment: Do you have this problem with your website? If so, what is the URL, so we can check the whole thing in context.

Comment: @Mr Lister sorry just working localhost. There is other problem just trying to understand why this does not work. Thanks

Comment: If it's simple, non-dynamic HTML, you can upload it to any storage site. Just make sure you still have the problem when viewing it there.

Comment: @Mr Lister I do not have the problem when I view using FF at jsfiddle, so it would imply that some of my markup is interfering with the display.

Comment: That's why we need to see all of it - not just a snippet.

Comment: @Mr Lister I have put more code at: http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/

Comment: the code you put at http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/ works fine in Chrome and IE10. So show us as much code as possible that breaks the design. (This will probably show you where the problem is)

Comment: @Mr Lister please see: http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/1/ Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you've written should work, and indeed as you see from the other comments and answers, it does work when used in isolation.

The most likely reason why your CSS wouldn't work is if something else in your CSS is being applied in preference over it. CSS has a strict order of precedence for selectors, and it would be quite easy to write a selector that was considered higher precedence than `a[title]`.

I suggest taking a look at the element in your browser dev tools (ie Firebug, etc) to determine what styles are being applied to it, and by what selectors.

If I'm right, you will see the `a[title]` styles are there, but are crossed out because other styles have been applied as well that have higher precedence.

Here's an article that describes [the CSS order of precedence](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/topics/cascade.htm).

There are four ways I can suggest to get around this problem:

1. Adapt your `a[title]` selector so that it has higher precedence than the other selectors. This would typically mean making it more precise, eg `.newsSpace>a[title]`.
2. Adapt the other selectors so that they have lower precedence.
3. Add `!important` to the end of your styles, to force the browser to give them maximum precedence. (this is the "quick win" option, but should be considered a last resort; using `!important` typically means you're doing something wrong elsewhere)
4. Change your HTML to give the element its own class or ID, and use that for your selector instead of `a[title]`.

Hope that helps.

**[EDIT]**

OP has commented below with an updated fiddle link, and I can now see the problem:

Okay, thanks for the updated link. I can now see `#menu li div a[title]` in the CSS code.

Looking at the element in question using Chrome Dev Tools (F12), I can see that all the styles for that are being applied successfully to your `Signout` element. However, the `font-size` property is being overridden by `#menu li:hover div a`, which is classed as being more specific due to the `:hover`.

Since the element is only visible when it's being hovered, the solution would seem to be simple: just add the same `:hover` property to `#menu li div a[title]` as is applied to the other selector.

So change it to `#menu li:hover div a[title]`

Here's your fiddle again, with that simple change made to it: http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/3/

Comment: I have posted full code and css at: http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/1/ would grateful if you could point out where the error is. Thanks

Comment: @user - I can't find `a[title]` in the fiddle you linked to. I can find `a .newsSpace`. That won't be selecting anything in the HTML you've given because the `a` and the `.newsSpace` are the wrong way round.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had copied the whole file. I have updated fiddle with title code. http://jsfiddle.net/TrScN/2/ Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 - Yep, the new fiddle is better. I've edited the answer to provide more help.

Comment: Sir thank you for your time and effort. Many thanks